# How to free up memory by removing unnecessary QGraphicsItems?

Tags: qt, memory-management

I have a `QGraphicsScene` with a large number of `QGraphicsPixmapItem`s, containing large pixmaps.

As a test, I added lots of items to the scene to make my program use hundreds of MB of memory.

After that, I tried removing them, with

- calling `ui->graphicsView->scene()->removeItem(item);` for every item
- resetting the pixmaps inside the items to empty pixmaps with `item->setPixmap(QPixmap());` for every item
- clearing the scene: `ui->graphicsView->scene()->clear();`

None of the above, either individually or used together, reduced the amount of used memory at all.

Note, that the `QGraphicsPixmapItem`s themselves are not deleted, they remain in a container. However, before using `setPixmap()` on them, they hardly use any memory.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: How do you test the memory usage of your app?

Comment: "What did I do wrong?" You're not measuring your memory use correctly. That's all.

Answer (score 2):

Try that:

```
foreach(QGraphicsItem *item, ui->graphicsView->scene()->items()) {
    delete item;
}
```

or, simply:

```
qDeletaAll( scene()->items() );
```

Note that you do not need to clear scene in any another way. QGraphicsScene can handle this and will not try to display deleted items.

clear() only removes it from scene but doesn't frees memory.

Comment: Both of them crash the application. The items are in an array and added to the scene via their pointers. I guess the problem should be in the Pixmaps, as that is what occupies so much memory, even without adding them to the scene.

Comment: If you app crashes after code I've pasted above, therefore you have problem somewhere else. For example, you use pointers to deleted item somewhere. That code works correctly on 100%, I'm using it in my own video player and I don't use any other methods for clear, only delete items. And I have no memory leaks or crashes.
I think problem starts here: "The items are in an array ". Why do you need that array? Scene items is accessible via items().

Comment: @vsz Where debugger shows crash? Go through stack after crash.

Comment: `munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer` , but it doesn't matter, as my items are not declared as pointers, so they can not be deleted. But that is not the goal here, the pixmaps inside them should be deleted.

Comment: @vsz, sorry, did I get you right that you adding stack variables to Scene? IT is bad way, but if you are using stack, therefore problem not in scene. What are you trying to reach? Scene doesn't copy something. You must clear your list therefore to clear memory.

Comment: [`QGraphicsScene::clear`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html#clear) removes items from the scene and deletes those items.